# Postgres backup script not emailing

Tags: postgresql, debian, mutt

I am using autopostgresqlbackup to backup my PostgreSQL database on Debian 8.3. Everything works except the zipped backup does not get emailed to me. When I run the script with "sudo autopostgresqlbackup" I get:

```
Can't stat <redacted name>@gmail.com: No such file or directory
<redacted name>@gmail.com: unable to attach file.
```

From my research this may be caused by mutt requiring "the -a option must be placed at the end of command line options"

The relevant part of the script itself seems to be:

```
ATTSIZE=`du -c $BACKUPFILES | grep "[[:digit:][:space:]]total$" |sed s/\s*total//`
        if [ $MAXATTSIZE -ge $ATTSIZE ]
        then
                if which biabam >/dev/null 2>&1
                then
                        BACKUPFILES=$(echo $BACKUPFILES | sed -r -e 's#\s+#,#g')
                        biabam -s "PostgreSQL Backup Log and SQL Files for $HOST - $DATE" $BACKUPFILES $MAILADDR < $LOGFILE
                elif which heirloom-mailx >/dev/null 2>&1
                then
                        BACKUPFILES=$(echo $BACKUPFILES | sed -e 's# # -a #g')
                        heirloom-mailx -s "PostgreSQL Backup Log and SQL Files for $HOST - $DATE" $BACKUPFILES $MAILADDR < $LOGFILE
                elif which mutt >/dev/null 2>&1
                then
                        BACKUPFILES=$(echo $BACKUPFILES | sed -e 's# # -a #g')
                        mutt -s "PostgreSQL Backup Log and SQL Files for $HOST - $DATE" $BACKUPFILES $MAILADDR < $LOGFILE
                else
                        cat "$LOGFILE" | mail -s "WARNING! - Enable to send PostgreSQL Backup dumps, no suitable mail client found on $HOST - $DATE" $MAILADDR
                fi
        else
                cat "$LOGFILE" | mail -s "WARNING! - PostgreSQL Backup exceeds set maximum attachment size on $HOST - $DATE" $MAILADDR
```

I have tried to reverse the order of "-a #g" in the above code, but then I get errors. Everything works fine if have the script backup Postgres and just send a log, but not if I have it email the backup file. Any ideas why the email attachment is not working?

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED:** Changed the order of  "$BACKUPFILES $MAILADDR < $LOGFILE" to  "$MAILADDR $BACKUPFILES < $LOGFILE" for mutt, and this stopped mutt from trying to attached the email address as an attachment, and thus failing.

Like so:

```
mutt -s "PostgreSQL Backup Log and SQL Files for $HOST - $DATE" $MAILADDR $BACKUPFILES < $LOGFILE
```